# MVC: View to Model interaction example

Tags: model-view-controller

There're a plenty of [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Interactions) that state that in MVC architecture, the View can interact directly with Model, namely to ask for the data.

What would a real world example of View to Model interactions look like? When would a programmer pass data via Controller and when will he allow View to retrieve it directly from Model?

P.S. MVC is heavily used in web development, but, as far as I am concerned, View is always interacting with Model through Controller.

Comment: what would you classify as real world example?

Comment: @wero, Any link to an example written in whatever there is language or just  a common description of a situation when View interacts with Model

Answer (score 0):

In this example the view is using Razor to render. This demonstrates the view instantiating the data request using jQuery.Get() after the ActionResult has been served back to the client

This is the Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSomeData()
    {
        return Json(new GetSomeDataModel{
            StringBar = "This is StringBar. And BoolBar: ";
            BoolBar = false;
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Model for the Data, not the view.

```
public class GetSomeDataModel
{
    public bool BoolBar {get;set;}
    public string StringBar {get;set;}
}
```

This is the View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Index Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts
{
    //And now we make a second request to the controller for the data...
    $.get( "@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "Home")", function( data ) {
        alert( "Load was performed." ); 
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on cases when passing data via controller is preferable to direct view-model requests? Is it just based on request complexity?

Comment: The reason you would choose to load data is pieces is because it isn't all needed to complete a response. Check out lazy load and eager load.